# How to reset Map or remove the MapRoute from Here Map

Tags: android, kotlin, maps, here-api

I am working on Basic Positioning and Navigation. I have used Bottom Navigation Tabs.

In MainActivity I have added MapFragment in XML file. This MapFragment is I am calling from Click of Tabs.

When I am clicking Location first time current location displayed correct. After I am clicking to Trip (Navigation),
Navigation is displayed correct, this scenario working fine.

But when I am clicking on Location, Navigation route is not removed. As shown figure.

Also I have used static variable of **MapRoute**

```
private static MapRoute mapRoute;
```

I have remove Map Object as following code snippet.

```
 if (map != null && mapRoute != null) {
        map.removeMapObject(mapRoute1);
        mapRoute = null;
    }
```

Now my question id how can remove or restart the static **MapFragment**.

[image: Current Location]

For Current Location I have used CurrentLocationFragmentView class as follow code snippet.

```
public class CurrentLocationFragmentView {
private    MapFragment m_mapFragment=null;
private Activity m_activity;
private   Map map=null;
private double langitude, latitude;
private static MapRoute mapRoute;
public CurrentLocationFragmentView(Activity activity,Double  Lat, Double lang) {
    m_activity = activity; 
    latitude=Lat;
    langitude=lang;
    initialize();

}
private void initialize() {

    // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
    m_mapFragment = (MapFragment) m_activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    m_mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                map=null;
                map = m_mapFragment.getMap();

                if (map != null && mapRoute != null) {
                    map.removeMapObject(mapRoute1);
                    mapRoute= null;
                } 
                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(latitude, langitude, 0.0),
                        Map.Animation.NONE);
                map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2); 
                map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);  
            }  
        }
    });
}
```

How to remove this **Route on Map** in Here Maps.

Comment: I see your are removing mapRoute1. Where does MapRoute1 come from?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I have edited my question ,Please check. There is an problem on posting code.I have declared **Maproute** variable as **mapRoute1**

Comment: Double check if you do not add same route twice on the map, removeMapObject does not remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use our latest HERE Android SDK version 3.14 and check if you have not added the same route twice on the map. `removeMapObject` will not remove duplicate routes.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-objects-and-interaction.html